How to plot a custom indicator (different indicator for different symbols) depending of what is the main symbol displayed in the chart?
I have created 2 customized indexes-indicators one for big 4 techs and other for 4 big banks. I would like to be able to tell trandingview which one to use depending on the working-ticker displayed.
this is indicator-index.1, named "Tech_idx" (big tech):
tindicator(title = "Big.tech", shorttitle = "BigTech", overlay = false)

sec_1_t =  request.security("NASDAQ:AAPL", timeframe.period, close) 
sec_2_t =  request.security("NASDAQ:MSFT", timeframe.period, close)
sec_3_t =  request.security("NASDAQ:GOOGL", timeframe.period, close) 
sec_4_t =  request.security("NASDAQ:AMZN", timeframe.period, close) 

Tech_idx = sec_1_t*0.25+sec_2_t*0.25+sec_3_t*0.25+sec_4_t*0.25

plot(Tech_idx, title="Tech_i", color=color.blue)

And similary indicator-index.2, named "Bank_idx", (big four banks):
tyindicator(title = "Big.Banks", shorttitle = "BigBanks", overlay = false)

sec_1_b =  request.security("NYSE:JPM", timeframe.period, close) 
sec_2_b =  request.security("NYSE:BAC", timeframe.period, close)
sec_3_b =  request.security("NYSE:WFC", timeframe.period, close) 
sec_4_b =  request.security("NYSE:GS", timeframe.period, close) 

Bank_idx = sec_1_b*0.25+sec_2_b*0.25+sec_3_b*0.25+sec_4_b*0.25

plot(Bank_idx, title="Bank_i", color=color.blue)

Now i would like to be able to tell tradingview that if "JPM" (JPMorgan) is the working-ticker, then bring "Bank_idx" as the indicator to display, but if "AAPL" (APPLE) is the working-ticker, then bring "Tech_idx" as the indicator to display , otherwise Null.

in a similar fashion, I know how to call SECURITIES, but it does not work for calling INDICATORS and I do not find other way:
ticker = syminfo.ticker
var string b = 

ticker == "JPM" ? "XLF" : 
ticker == "AAPL" ? "XLK" : 

NULL

secB = request.security(b, timeframe.period, close) 

plot(secB, title="b", color=color.blue)

I would appreciate help, kind regards

I tried to do the something similar and didn´t find a reference in the tutorial. I have a dashboard for my top 8 stocks. On some days, these 8 are lame and I want to switch the dashboard to the next stocks. I just added my indicator twice, the one I don´t want / need, I simply disable it, it´s just 2 clicks with the mouse. Not the solution I wanted and maybe you are lookig for, but it works

You can do that in an ugly way only. You can attach both indicators to the same chart, make some conditionals in both and based on that one of them should display values and the other would not display anything (or both would not do anything).
Put both logic into a single indicator and make a decision at the display level.
